# C++ Very weird behavior while using int in switch

Tags: c++, int, switch-statement, case

I'm getting some very strange behaviour using the following switch statement:

```
string recognise_mti(int mti_code)
{
switch(mti_code)
    {
    case 1100:
    case 1101:
        return (mti_code + " (Auth. Request/Repeat)"); break;

    default:
        return (mti_code + " (NOT RECOGNISED)"); break;
    }
}
```

It seems to return all sorts of things depending on the input integer. It's probably going to turn out to be a silly mistake but as of yet, I'm unable to recognise it. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You might want to elaborate more about the received results.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but when doing `return` as the only thing in a `case` you don't need the `break`. The reason being that `return` returns, and the `break` wont be executed. Of course, a modern compiler would probably notice this and not generate code for the `break`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither `mti_code` nor `" (Auth. Request/Repeat)"` is a `std::string`.  So in fact, all that addition is going to do is pointer addition.  So you'll end up with a somewhat random (and probably invalid) pointer, which is then implicitly converted to a `std::string`.

Try this:

```
#include <sstream>

...

std::stringstream ss;
ss << mti_code;
switch(mti_code)
    {
    case 1100:
    case 1101:
        ss << " (Auth. Request/Repeat)"; break;

    default:
        ss << " (NOT RECOGNISED)"; break;
    }
return ss.str();
```

Comment: Ah thanks for the explanation and help, makes sense now, bit of a silly (and embarrassing) mistake, I have to say. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are adding an integer and a string literal. That's not exactly typical in C++ code.

What is likely happening is that you're returning a string constructed from an invalid character pointer, since the literals are (way) shorter than 1100 characters.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to add an integer to a C-style string, which doesn't do what you expect. The string is converted to a pointer to its first character, and then that pointer is incremented by 1100 (or whatever) bytes, off the end of the string, and into random memory. If you're lucky, the program will crash; if you're unlucky, then the function will return garbage.

You could use a string stream to build the string:

```
std::ostringstream result;
switch(mti_code)
{
case 1100:
case 1101:
    result << mti_code << " (Auth. Request/Repeat)"; break;

default:
    result << mti_code << " (NOT RECOGNISED)"; break;
}
return result.str();
```

or in C++11, you could use `std::to_string` to convert the integer:

```
return std::to_string(mti_code) + " (Auth. Request/Repeat)";
```

Comment: Which compilers support C++11?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to append a string to an integer. That is not possible in C or C++. You have to convert the integer to a string somehow, [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) is the recommended way:

```
std::string recognise_mti(const int mti_code)
{
    std::ostringstream ostr;

    switch(mti_code)
    {
    case 1100:
    case 1101:
        ostr << mti_code << " (Auth. Request/Repeat)";
        break;

    default:
        ostr << mti_code << " (NOT RECOGNISED)";
        break;
    }

    return ostr.str();
}
```

Or if you have a compiler supporting C++11 and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) you can use that:

```
std::string recognise_mti(const int mti_code)
{
    switch(mti_code)
    {
    case 1100:
    case 1101:
        return std::to_string(mti_code) + " (Auth. Request/Repeat)";

    default:
        return std::to_string(mti_code) + " (NOT RECOGNISED)";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do see that you're adding an integer value to an address of the first byte of a given string literal? This is basically undefined behavior, since you're making an offset of, let's say, 1100 to the "right" (since we're talking about chars, that's the address of something located 1100 bytes down the memory street). For example, in my example, if I try to offset the given string literal's address by 1100, I get "being initialized." That's because the offset address is returned and implicitly converted into a string which gets read as whatever is located at the given address.

Could be anything, my example string, "crazy elephants" or the secret way to enable full C++11 support in MSVC. :P

If I were to try to offset it by one more char (one byte, one offset to the right):

```
recognise_mti(1100);  // "being initialized."  
recognise_mti(1101); // "eing initialized."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate an integer and a string literal with `+`. You need to convert the integer to a string first. You can do this with a `stringstream` or with `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding an `int` to a `const char*` and returning that as a `string`.